# Java readline whitespace

Tags: java, whitespace, readline

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");

// Get the object of DataInputStream
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
  {
    //Test if it is a line we need
    if(strLine.charAt(0) != ' ' && strLine.charAt(5) == ' '
       && strLine.charAt(10) == ' ' && strLine.charAt(15) == ' '
       && strLine.charAt(20) == ' ' && strLine.charAt(25) == ' ' )
      {
        System.out.println (strLine);
      }
  }
```

I am reading in a file with lines of whitespace(not only whitespace) and comparing chars at certain indexes to see if I need the line however when I read in a line of whitespace I get a string index out of range.

Comment: Can you provide some code illustrating your issue?

Comment: Need to see some code to help you out ...

Answer (score 2):

If the line is length 0 and you are trying to determine the character at location 10 for example you are going to get an exception. Just put in a check to see if the line is not all whitespace before processing it.

```
if (line != null && line.trim().length() > 0)
{
   //process this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty line will not be null, but and empty string ''. It will break if you try and read the character at index 0.

```
 while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
 {
    //remove whitespace infront and after contents of line.
    strLine = strLine.trim();

    if (strLine.equals(""))
      continue;

     //check that string has at least 25 characters when trimmed.
    if (strLine.length() <25)  
       continue;

    //Test if it is a line we need
    if(strLine.charAt(0) != ' ' && strLine.charAt(5) == ' ' && strLine.charAt(10) == ' ' && strLine.charAt(15) == ' ' && strLine.charAt(20) == ' ' && strLine.charAt(25) == ' ' )
    {
         System.out.println (strLine);
    }
 }
```

You can also try and use the Java Scanner class. It is really useful for reading in files.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is the checking the charter till 25th character using `strLine.charAt(25)` whereas your `String strLine` may not have those many characters. The `charAt(int index)` method will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `index` argument is not less than the length of this string.

You can find the length of `strLine` by calling `strLine.length()` and then check the `charAt()` from `0` to `strLine.length() - 1` and you will not see that exception.